# Using paypal at AdMob

Tags: android, paypal, admob, account

I would like to use AdMob in order to publish banners at my Android App, so i can earn something for my hard work.

I would like to use PayPal as my payment manager, but i don't have paypal account. I saw that there are 2 types of Paypal account types (in Israel there are only 2 types):

- individual
- business

I don't have a company - do i need to sign in as individual? and if i have individual account - will AdMob will be able to transfer my revenues?
thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Yes, both accounts are able to receive money. A 'business' can also be a sole proprietorship. But this definitely isn't a question for SO. I'd suggest calling PayPal and asking them. (Besides, you can always upgrade from an individual account to a business account.)

Answer (score 2):

You need a Individual Paypal account.
And yes, Admob will transfer your money to you.

> However, if your total payable earnings are less than $20 at the end of a month (or $100 for international wire payments), AdMob rolls your earnings over to the following month. For example, if you earn $10 in January and $50 in February, a payment is be sent to you for $60 in early to mid-April.